# Gradle error after import module library

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, module

Here is what I got from the error message:

> Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :library:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:mockableAndroidJar, :library:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
>       Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>       Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.>     Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>       Information:BUILD FAILED
>       Information:Total time: 3.008 secs
>       Information:2 errors
>       Information:0 warnings
>       Information:See complete output in console

message :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.>
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.212 secs
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :library:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:mockableAndroidJar, :library:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Using the 'clean' task in combination with parallel execution may lead to unexpected runtime behavior.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:library:clean
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl
:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseShaders
:library:compileReleaseShaders
:library:generateReleaseAssets
:library:mergeReleaseAssets
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript
:library:generateReleaseResValues
:library:generateReleaseResources
:library:packageReleaseResources
:library:processReleaseManifest
:library:bundleRelease
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
:library:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportConstraintConstraintLayout101Library
:library:prepareDebugDependencies
:library:compileDebugAidl
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
:library:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:library:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:library:generateDebugResValues
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library
:library:generateDebugResources
:library:mergeDebugResources
:app:prepareComJakewhartonButterknife881Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file
:library:processDebugManifest
:library:processDebugResources
Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should comment `org.gradle.parallel = true` in gradle.properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've rebuild without module, just use dependencies and it works.
This might be useful next time.

Answer (score 0):

Check your drawable resource/images bundled. One of them or few of them might not be the proper .png files

> AAPT: libpng error: Not a PNG file

Solution open the file which is not correct in an editor and save it with same name and correct .png extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i've rebuild without module, just use dependencies and it works.
I really did not see that.
This might be useful next time.